# Erro de Complexidade: Access

Tags: sql, microsoft-access

Estou fazendo uma consulta de palavras dentro de alguns campos e utilizo varios likes. Porém com isso está dando erro de complexidade no Access, alguém pode me ajudar?

```
IIF((tx_rspt_a LIKE '*AFEGAN*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*BIELORR*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*BOSNIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*BURUNDI*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*CONGO*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*COREIA DO NORT*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*COSTA DO MARF*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*CUBA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*EGITO*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*ERITREI*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*GUINE*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*IEMEN*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE 'IRÃ')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*IRAQUE*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*LIBANO*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*LIBERIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*LIBIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*MALI*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*MIANMAR*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*MONTENEGRO*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*NICARAGUA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*RUSSIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*SERRA LEOA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*SERVIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*SIRIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*SOMALIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*SUDAO*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*TUNISIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*UCRANIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*VENEZUELA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*ZIMBABUE*'),1,0) AS PAISES_PROIBIDOS_PF,
IIF((tx_rspt_a LIKE '*AFEGAN*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*AFRICA DO SUL*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*ALBANIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*ALEMANHA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*ANDORRA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*ANGOLA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*ANTIGA E BARBUDA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*ARABIA SAUDITA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*ARGELIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*ARGENTINA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*ARMENIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*AUSTRALIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*AUSTRIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*AZERBAIJAO*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*BAHAMAS*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*BANGLADEXE*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*BARBADOS*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*BAREM*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*BELGICA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*BELIZE*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*BENIM*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*BOLIVIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*BOTSUANA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*BRASIL*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*BRUNEI*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*BULGARIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*BURQUINA FASO*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*BUTAO*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*CABO VERDE*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*CAMAROES*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*CAMBOJA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*CANADA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*CATAR*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*CAZAQUISTAO*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*CHADE*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*CHILE*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*CHINA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*CHIPRE*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*COLOMBIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*COMORES*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*COREIA DO SUL*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*COSOVO*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*COSTA RICA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*CROACIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*CUAITE*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*DINAMARCA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*DOMINICA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*EMIRADOS ARABES UNIDOS*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*EQUADOR*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*ESLOVAQUIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*ESLOVENIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*ESPANHA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*ESTADO DA PALESTINA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*ESTADOS UNIDOS*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*ESTONIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*ETIOPIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*FIJI*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*FILIPINAS*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*FINLANDIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*FRANCA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*GABAO*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*GAMBIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*GANA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*GEORGIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*GRANADA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*GRECIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*GUATEMALA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*GUIANA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*GUINE EQUATORIAL*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*HAITI*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*HONDURAS*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*HUNGRIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*ILHAS MARECHAL*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*INDIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*INDONESIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*IRLANDA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*ISLANDIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*ISRAEL*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*ITALIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*JAMAICA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*JAPAO*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*JIBUTI*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*JORDANIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*LAUS*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*LESOTO*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*LETONIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*LISTENSTAINE*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*LITUANIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*LUXEMBURGO*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*MACEDONIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*MADAGASCAR*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*MALASIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*MALAUI*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*MALDIVAS*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*MALTA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*MARROCOS*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*MAURICIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*MAURITANIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*MEXICO*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*MICRONESIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*MOCAMBIQUE*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*MOLDAVIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*MONACO*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*MONGOLIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*NAMIBIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*NAURU*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*NEPAL*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*NIGER*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*NIGERIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*NORUEGA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*NOVA ZELANDIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*OMA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*PAISES BAIXOS*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*PALAU*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*PANAMA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*PAPUA NOVA GUINE*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*PAQUISTAO*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*PARAGUAI*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*PERU*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*POLONIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*PORTUGAL*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*QUENIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*QUIRGUISTAO*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*QUIRIBATI*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*REINO UNIDO*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*REPUBLICA CENTRO-AFRICANA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*REPUBLICA CHECA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*REPUBLICA DOMINICANA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*ROMENIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*RUANDA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*SALOMAO*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*SALVADOR*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*SAMOA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*SANTA LUCIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*SAO CRISTOVAO E NEVES*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*SAO MARINHO*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*SAO TOME E PRINCIPE*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*SAO VICENTE E GRANADINAS*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*SEICHELES*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*SENEGAL*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*SINGAPURA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*SRI LANCA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*SUAZILANDIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*SUECIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*SUICA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*SURINAME*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*TAILANDIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*TAIUA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*TAJIQUISTAO*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*TANZANIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*TIMOR-LESTE*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*TOGO*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*TONGA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*TRINDADE E TOBAGO*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*TURCOMENISTAO*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*TURQUIA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*TUVALU*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*UGANDA*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*URUGUAI*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*USBEQUISTAO*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*VANUATU*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*VATICANO*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*VIETNAME*')
OR (tx_rspt_a LIKE '*ZAMBIA*'),1,0) AS PAISES_LIBERADOS_PF
```

Answer (score 0):

Algo que funciona no SQL e que deve funcionar no Access seria criar uma tabela auxiliar com estes padrões de pesquisa e fazer um JOIN com LIKE com esta tabela que você está utilizando

Por exemplo, se você criar uma tabela chamada "pesquisa" com um campo chamado "conteudo", onde cada linha seja um dos valores que você quer pesquisar `('*AFEGAN*', *BIELORR*, *BOSNIA*, *BURUNDI*)...`

Você poderia fazer um JOIN com a sua tabela atual desta forma:

```
SELECT t.* FROM minha_tabela t JOIN pesquisa p ON (t.tx_rspt_a LIKE p.conteudo);
```

Comment: Então, é que com o JOIN, ele vai retornar só as linhas que ele encontrou as palavras. Mas no caso, eu retorno como se fosse um resultado, por exemplo.
Se no texto " fiz um câmbio de XXX em Israel" , ele identifica a palavra e retorna em uma coluna "1" se encontrou e "0" se não encontrou.